# How to get the local_rank attribute

Tags: python, machine-learning

the Engine code is as follows:

```
class Engine(object):
    def __init__(self, cfg, custom_parser=None):
        self.version = 0.01
        self.state = State()
        self.devices = None
        self.distributed = False
        self.logger = None
        self.cfg = cfg

        if custom_parser is None:
            self.parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
        else:
            assert isinstance(custom_parser, argparse.ArgumentParser)
            self.parser = custom_parser

        self.inject_default_parser()
        self.args = self.parser.parse_args()

        self.continue_state_object = self.args.continue_fpath

        if 'WORLD_SIZE' in os.environ:
            self.distributed = int(os.environ['WORLD_SIZE']) > 1

        if self.distributed:
            self.local_rank = self.args.local_rank
            self.world_size = int(os.environ['WORLD_SIZE'])
            self.world_rank = int(os.environ['RANK'])
            torch.cuda.set_device(self.local_rank)
            dist.init_process_group(backend="nccl", init_method='env://')
            dist.barrier()
            self.devices = [i for i in range(self.world_size)]
        else:
            # todo check non-distributed training
            self.world_rank = 1
            self.devices = parse_torch_devices(self.args.devices)

    def setup_log(self, name='train', log_dir=None, file_name=None):
        if not self.logger:
            self.logger = get_logger(
                name, log_dir, self.args.local_rank, filename=file_name)
        else:
            self.logger.warning('already exists logger')
        return self.logger
```

I want to get local_rank,but when I just use Engine.local_rank ,it returns AttributeError: type object 'Engine' has no attribute 'local_rank'
like this
[image]

Comment: Engine.local_rank is not the same as self.local_rank. Engine.local_rank suggests local_rank is a class variable, not an instance variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `local_rank` depends on `self.distributed==True` or `self.distributed!=0` which means `'WORLD_SIZE'` needs to be in `os.environ` so just add the environment variable `WORLD_SIZE` (which should be an integer)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think I have already made it clear